# Using javascript with a local html file to delete itself?

Tags: javascript, html, file-permissions, delete-file, chromebook

I coded a local html file that kind of works like windows notepad would, using `localStorage` with JavaScript to auto save. To make new notes, I have just been saving the open file as another `.html` file and naming it something new for the note. But I have found this to be really annoying, because when I want to delete the note, I have to actually go into my Files app, find the `.html` file for the note, and delete it.

I know how to use event listeners and whatever, but is there a line of code I can use to delete the file or even just ask the user for confirmation to delete the file? I basically need a way for a local html file to be able to delete itself using JavaScript. Everything I have managed to find online says that you need Node.js and it has to be on a server, but I wanted to ask anyway, because I wonder if permissions are different when the file is stored locally and not on a server.

Comment: Why don't you just use separate localStorage items for each note? JavaScript can't delete files by itself.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can't use browser JavaScript to manipulate the real local filesystem. (You could [access a sandboxed one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem), but not the real filesystem.)

Comment: But it’s not really browser JavaScript, it’s JavaScript within the local file system that’s being ran. Wouldn’t that have permission at least over itself?

Comment: What is running the JavaScript? It's the browser, isn't it? Either way: no.